# Difference between setting onClickListener in adapter and in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-gridview

In my code I have fragment and gridview in it. Also I have ArrayAdapter for this Gridview. Now I need to change background color of grid cell on click. I do this by setting onClickListener.

Question is what is difference between setting onClickLister for GridView cell in adapter and in fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna try to clarify the different android entities involved in your question a little.

A `GridView` is a `View`.

- You can assign Click Listeners to Views so they react to a user click. Any view has a generic clicklistener (`View.setOnClickListener`) that gets called whenever the user clicks on any part of the view
- Complex views can have several other more specialized clicklisteners, for example, menu-like views (ListViews, GridViews, etc) will have also a `setOnItemClickListener` / `setOnItemLongClickListener` that gets called whenever the user clicks on an item (vs. the whole view)

An `Adapter` is just a class whose purpose is to build views with data to data-consuming views. For example, your `GridViewAdapter`: It will get called once for every row and it will construct each Row View (in the getView method). Every Row View will be (probably) a `ViewGroup` (`FrameLayout`/`RelativeLayout`...) with some other views inside (ie. Icon `ImageView`, name `TextView`, address...)

So the adapter itself doesn't accept clicklisteners. But the Views created by the adapter can! For example, let's assume your `GridView` is a Phone List:

- Your `GridView` has an `ItemClickListener` to react to the selected phone list entry and show info about the contact
- Your `GridView` adapter builds views for every row. Imagine your 'contact' rows have 3 views: A title, an Icon, and a button to delete the contact
- Inside your adapter, you will assign an onClickListener to the "delete contact" button **View**. Mind you always assign `onClickListeners` to Views, not to the adapter itself ("you can't click an adapter!")
- About Fragments, think of them as "sub-activities". A fragment contains a root layout with several views. Again, it will be in those views where you assign the clicklisteners, not to the fragment itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I see it now I asked my question wrong. What I wanted to know is there any difference between calling `convertView.setOnClickListener` in `getView` method of adapter class and  `GridView.setOnItemClickListener` in my fragment?

Comment: uh, that's actually an interesting question. In typical situations you should do it from outside the adapter if the view supports it: Your adapter will be more generic and prone to reusability. In the adapter try to keep things with as little application logic as possible. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893313/onclicklistener-on-adapter-x-onitemclicklistener-on-listview.

Comment: However there are situations where doing it inside the adapter would make sense: Imagine you have a complex row with a lot of sub-elements, and you want to capture the clicking on the container to do something with the sub-elements (without affecting the application logic, just for example rearranging them). In this case it makes sense because the click-action is not related to the application but only to the row itself